# Can I form a direct URL to a particular Gmail account?

Tags: gmail

Since Gmail implemented multiple sign-on, I have been unable to create a bookmark URL that will always go to my "@gmail.com" inbox. For hosted domains, it's easy enough to make the bookmark URL: `https://mail.google.com/a/example.com` will always take you to your `@example.com` inbox. However, this does not work with `@gmail.com` addresses. I am aware of the `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/[number]` address form, however this address is dependent on the order in which you signed in to accounts during this browser session, and thus is not an acceptable URL that will **always** go to the same place.

Is there any URL that will always take me to `@gmail.com` address, assuming I am logged in to that account?

Javascript bookmarklets would be acceptable, but anything involving a plugin or add-on is not acceptable.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to bookmark a Google calendar or inbox for a specific account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86559/33787)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=user@gmail.com

Seems to work quite fine for me.

Comment: This does not work for me. It takes me to the gmail login screen, but the user line is not pre-filled. I think this answer is out of date now.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo - This answer still works for me. This question assumes that you are already logged in to your account.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Seems to work for Google Drive too: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/?authuser=user@gmail.com

Comment: Better alternative: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/user@gmail.com. This has the benefit of adding parameters, such as https://drive.google.com/drive/u/user@gmail.com/search?q=asdf, useful for custom search queries

Comment: This worked for me *if* you are already logged into the account in question.  It also works for google-hosted/google apps accounts with a different domain, eg. `authuser=myself@MyCustomDomain.ViaGoogleApps.etc`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, takes me to login screen because that user is not the default Chrome user

Comment: You can also use https://mail.google.com/mail/user@gmail.com/#inbox/id to deep link to a message

Comment: This appears to work for GMail and Drive but not for Maps. It is a shame this it isn't consistent.

Comment: Doesn't work for Google Sheets.

Answer (score 33):

Yes, once you are logged in, you can simply use your email address instead of the `[number]` in your URL. For example: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/example@gmail.com; this also works for Google Apps domains.

This also works great to go to a specific email, or filter, or so, with: 
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/example@gmail.com/#inbox/153d2095719946b

If you are not logged in to your example@gmail.com account yet, but to another account, then the link will not work and show "The conversation that you requested no longer exists."

Comment: Works as well as the accepted answer, and has the virtue of being shorter.

Comment: This works for me, unlike the accepted answer

Comment: This also appears to work for third-party GSuite domains (i.e. `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/user@university.edu`), whereas using `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=user@university.edu` redirects to the default mailbox for me.

Answer (score 24):

Combining the information from the other answers with a fair bit of research, I believe this is the best way of referring to a particular GMail account:

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&Email=example@domain.com&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/example@domain.com/
```

This will redirect through accounts.google.com, making the relevant Email address log in if it isn't already logged in, and just select it if it is logged in.  (If you remove passive=true, you'll always prompt for password.)

If you want to redirect to a particular fragment under GMail (e.g. to display a particular mail or contact), just URL encode the # as %23 - so add %23inbox/152bc41f0ca2d9bf at the end, like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&Email=example@domain.com&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/example@domain.com/%23inbox/152bc41f0ca2d9bf
```

If what you want to do is create a pre-filled email, use a variant like the following:

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&Email=example@domain.com&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/example@domain.com/?view=cm%26fs=1%26to=someone@example.com%26su=SUBJECT%26body=BODY%26bcc=someone.else@example.com
```

Hat tip to [robertwbradford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852679/2258778) for the parameters for send.

Comment: any way to pre-fill the password?

Comment: @Kim No. Absolutely and specifically not. That would be horrific user security. If you need to authorise on behalf of a user, use OAuth2.

Comment: Any tips on how to get a space into the body? I've tried + and %20 and &nbsp and they all break the link. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It turns out that you have to use %2B for spaces because those convert into + when the url is processed.

Comment: This is the best solution. Works when your already login too.

Comment: This is SO CLOSE to perfect.  If I'm already logged into all my accounts, this URL form will redirect to the correct mailbox.  If I'm completely signed out, it will prompt for login first.  But if I am logged into ONE account and use the URL for the other, then Google can't be bothered to prompt for login because I'm ALREADY logged in -- so it skips the login and redirects to the WRONG account, just because it's logged in and the right account isn't.  It will prompt for the login with "passive=false", but then it ALWAYS does.  Why does Google's identity management suck so bad? It's ridiculous.

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40447671/178551) solves the problem @DevenT.Corzine describes.

Answer (score 6):

Try this out, the below URL seems to be working for me:

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fgmail.google.com%2Fgmail&service=mail&Email=`youremail@gmail.com`

Though I couldn't pre fill password

Comment: This works for me. This url does not assume you are already logged in.

Comment: Man, what prefilling of password are you talking about. Delete this and go learn some basic internet security before even using internet

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to how you can form a URL to take you to a particular inbox, you can also form a URL to take you directly to a particular contact in a particular Gmail account like so:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=yourname@gmail.com&?shva=1#contact/0123456789ABCDEF
```

Where `0123456789ABCDEF` is the unique 16 character contact ID within that account.

After the `?authuser` you include the `&?shva=#1contact/` takes you the contact list for that user. You must include both characters `&?`.

This works regardless of how many Gmail accounts you are simultaneously logged into and regardless of login order. The `?authuser` replaces the 0, 1, 2, etc. that Gmail typically substitutes.