# Permalink to specific Gmail inbox

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

Gmail's multiple account support distinguishes between Gmail accounts with just an index, which simply reflects the order in which you signed into Gmail:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/
...

So if you sign into Gmail first with `test@example.com` and then with `notatest@gmail.com`, https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/ will go to the inbox of `test@example.com`; but if you sign into `notatest@gmail.com` before `test@example.com`, the same link will go to the inbox of `notatest@gmail.com`.

Aside from always signing into Google accounts in the same order, is there a good way to link to a specific Gmail account?

See also [this related question on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gmail-users/ainMZMH6VkY).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try the link below, changing the `test@example.com` value as needed.

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=test@example.com
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If I'm not logged in to Gmail at all, it prompts me to login (to any account). If I am logged in, it just jumps me to the default Google account.

Comment: Just checked this and this does work.

Comment: Excellent - thanks, Bob. Just tested and it works.

Comment: A related question that I didn't specifically ask: how to permalink to a specific message ID of a specific mailbox... but that's a different question :)

Comment: Related: Google Voice link to a specific account: `https://www.google.com/voice/?authuser=test@example.com`.  This only works correctly if you are already logged into the specified account though.

Comment: also works for inbox: https://inbox.google.com/u/?authuser=test@example.com

Comment: This works if you have already signed in to the account -- otherwise you'll get the behaviour described by @ale

Answer (score 0):

I found a URL in the answer to a [similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70594/12510). This works for me.

From the other answer:

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fgmail.google.com%2Fgmail&service=mail&Email=youremail@gmail.com
```

Just change `youremail` in the URL above to whatever your username is.

Comment: No longer works