# How to create a direct link to a gmail account that will take you to the login screen

Tags: gmail, google, google-multi-login

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18959/can-i-form-a-direct-url-to-a-particular-gmail-account) seems to be asking almost the same thing, but for some reason I can't get any of the answers to fully work in my situation.

I'm looking for a direct link I can put in a web app to navigate to the inbox of a specific gmail account, with the following use cases:

1. I would like a link to go to admin@domain.com (domain.com is a
   google workspace account).
2. If a user is logged into user1@gmail.com and NOT into
   admin@domain.com, I'd like to go to the account login page for
   admin@domain.com
3. If the user is not logged in to any gmail services (such as incognito), I'd like the link to go to the
   account login page for admin@domain.com (this is similar to 2, but google treats these differently)
4. If a user is logged into admin@domain.com, I'd like them to go to the inbox directly.

I tried all the answers on the linked question, but I found they all failed case 2 for me. They would invariably simply go to my first logged in inbox (user1@gmail.com) in my example.

I got further with [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97952) by setting the passive=false parameter, but while this did show me the login screen for case 2, it autofilled the information with user1@gmail.com.

Is there a way to create a link that would follow these use cases for a gmail inbox? Or at least, is there a link that would simply bring me to the login page for admin@domain.com from all possible starting points?

The webapp will also probably use the gmail api, so if it's possible with that, that would also work as a solution (I haven't had a deep dive into it, but I didn't see anything off the top that would give me a link through the api)

Answer (score 1):

Ended up finding an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384354/force-google-account-chooser) and combining this with the answer I linked in the question to get the following URL which satisfies the conditions (note that ServiceLogin has changed to AccountChooser).

> https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=mail&passive=true&Email=example@domain.com&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/example@domain.com

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).